# Not able to see SQL Developer Materialized View SQL

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

I am using SQL Developer Version 19.1.0.094.
We have a materialized view, and I was able to view the SQL that has 709 rows of code.

Then, we added more codes to the materialized view, and now it has 1162 rows of code.

After that, I am not able to view the SQL in the materialized view anymore.
I am able to view it on Toad.

Is there a limitation in SQL Developer, where I can only see Materialized View's SQL if it has fewer than certain number of rows/characters ?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of SQL developer to see if that resolves your issue? Is SQL Developer giving you an error when you try to look at the source code of the view?

Comment: Hi, there is no error, just not showing the SQL. I can see the codes up until "DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS", then there is no SELECT...after that

Comment: Have you tried using a newer version of SQL Developer?

Comment: I just installed the latest Version 19.2.1.247, and I have the same issue.

Comment: You got 19.2, which is stil a year old compared to 20.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have SQL developer right now to check, however you can see the query in following system views ,

***ALL_MVIEWS***

- Describes all mterialized views accessible to the current user

***USER_MVIEWS***

- Describes all materialized views owned by the current user.

In both views above column name `Query` is where you see the complete select statement used.

Answer (score 0):

If GUI doesn't work, SQL*Plus does. Use `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL`. For example:

```
SQL> create materialized view mv_dept as select * From dept;

Materialized view created.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW', 'MV_DEPT') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('MATERIALIZED_VIEW','MV_DEPT')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "SCOTT"."MV_DEPT" ("DEPTNO", "DNAME", "LOC")
  ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 NOCOMPRESS LOG
GING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DE
FAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS"
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX
  REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
  USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS select * From dept
```